# Can explicitly calling user-defined conversion functions be used to cast an object to a type found in its class body without qualifying the type name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

In the following code:

```cpp
struct S {
    using T = int; // could also be a nested class
    operator int() const { return 0; }
} s;

int main()
{
    auto a = s.operator T();    // (1)
    auto b = s.S::operator T(); // (2)
}
```

the name T is outside the scope of main but is only used in the context of a class member access. So, is the example well-formed?

C++20 in [basic.scope#class-6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope#class-6) says that the names of class members can be used in the right side of the . and in the right side of ::

> The name of a class member shall only be used as follows:

> [...]

> after the . operator applied to an expression of the type of its class ([expr.ref]) or a class derived from its class,

> [...]

> after the ​::​ scope resolution operator ([expr.prim.id.qual]) applied to the name of its class or a class derived from its class.

[basic.lookup#classref-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#classref-7) says that conversion functions first look up the name of the type in the class:

> If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its conversion-type-id is first looked up in the class of the object expression ([class.member.lookup]) and the name, if found, is used.
> Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.
> In each of these lookups, only names that denote types or templates whose specializations are types are considered.

Finally, [basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1.2) lets us apply the preceding clause to qualified lookup as well:

> a conversion-type-id of a conversion-function-id is looked up in the same manner as a conversion-type-id in a class member access (see [basic.lookup.classref]);

So, if my reading of the standard is correct, both (1) and (2) should be well-formed. In practice, GCC accepts both, Clang rejects both and MSVC only accepts (2). So, which compiler (if any) behaves correctly?

Comment: The literal answer to the question in the title is “no”. A function call is not a cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. A more sympathetic answer is that you can call a conversion function directly when you want to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker That was a mistake on my part. I only used the word cast in the title because of the character limit. I originally wrote convert. After all, the whole question is based on the fact that I can call user-defined conversion functions directly. The thing is, how does the compiler look up the function in this case? The name operator T should work (I think), however MSVC and clang require operator S::T. Anyway, this has already been answered over at the original question, so I guess I just have to read P1787.